# What Nutch command do I need to invoke from the command line if I update the url filter text

Tags: java, mapreduce, nutch, web-crawler

Nutch Gurus,

If I change files such as **robots.txt**, or **regex-urlfilter.txt** and any such resources, which command do I need to invoke?

I was not sure from the nutch instructions. I am guessing it is parser job, but I am not sure.

Kartik

From the instructions

```
# echo " crawl one-step crawler for intranets"
  echo " inject     inject new urls into the database"
  echo " hostinject     creates or updates an existing host table from a text file"
  echo " generate   generate new batches to fetch from crawl db"
  echo " fetch      fetch URLs marked during generate"
  echo " parse      parse URLs marked during fetch"
  echo " updatedb   update web table after parsing"
  echo " updatehostdb   update host table after parsing"
  echo " readdb     read/dump records from page database"
  echo " readhostdb     display entries from the hostDB"
  echo " elasticindex   run the elasticsearch indexer"
  echo " solrindex  run the solr indexer on parsed batches"
  echo " solrdedup  remove duplicates from solr"
  echo " parsechecker   check the parser for a given url"
  echo " indexchecker   check the indexing filters for a given url"
  echo " plugin     load a plugin and run one of its classes main()"
  echo " nutchserver    run a (local) Nutch server on a user defined port"
  echo " junit          runs the given JUnit test"
  echo " or"
  echo " CLASSNAME  run the class named CLASSNAME"
  echo "Most commands print help when invoked w/o parameters."
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the regex-urlfilter.txt file, you need to update the nutch job file. This can be done as:

`jar -uvf /usr/local/nutch-1.2/nutch-1.2.job <path to regex-urlfilter.txt>`